# ASP.NET Core 2 Windows Authentication/AD Get Groupmembers

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication, directoryservices

Like the title says, i need to get the members of a group from my Active directory.
Code:

```
    using(var p_con = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    {
        var grps = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(p_con, IdentityType.Sid, "S-1-5-21-205523278-2745993604-4001200492-1027");
        var users = grps.GetMembers();
    }
```

But my code throws the follwing error in the Membersproperty of the 'grps' var.

> Members = 'grps.Members' threw an exception of type
>   'System.TypeLoadException'

If i try it the other way, searching for the groups of a member, i get the same error.

```
    using (var p_con = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    {
        var up = new UserPrincipal(p_con);
        using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(up))
        {
            foreach (var user in search.FindAll())
            {
                var _grp = user.GetGroups();
            }
        }
    }
```

The group/user it self is correctly loaded except the Users\Groups.

Am i missing something in the setup?

I am using ASP.NET Core 2 and the current Windows.Compatibility Pack (which includes the current verion of the DirectoryServices).
The authentication runs via Http.sys

Comment: `TypeLoadException` usually means you're missing a reference in your project (or the reference you have isn't the version it's looking for). Is there more to the error message? It usually tells you what it can't find.

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that. Yep, the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumerable' Type is missing. I will try to implement it manually.

Comment: I guess you saw this then eh: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19731

Comment: Hmm, added the namespace via nuget 'System.Runtime.InteropServices -Version 4.3.0' and still facing this issue. So i think it must be some kind of a bug.

Comment: Ok, im sure its a bug, but is there a 'working' workaround? Sawed this Post: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26257 ,is not really usefull in my case. Should i switch to ldap?

Comment: The exception shown in that bug is not the same as yours though. The bug I linked to is the same as yours.